# Have omnifunc and completefunc take precedence over supertabs

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, supertab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking omnifunc before Supertags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785124/checking-omnifunc-before-supertags)

How do I have Vim check if any Omni completion or complete-functioning can be done before defaulting to Supertab completion? For example in a .html file I would enter

Answer (score 3):

I have the following settings for supertab:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabContextTextOmniPrecedence = ['&omnifunc', '&completefunc']
```

the setting `context` for supertabdefaultcompletion makes supertab use omni comppletion if the context is appropiate (eg, if you are in c++ file and type ::). If the context is not appropriate it will just return the default completion (`ctrl-p`).